# Find local maximum, minimum and saddle points of $f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 - 4xy + 2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, hessian-matrix

> Find maximum, minimum and saddle points of $f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 - 4xy + 2$.

For critical points, $f_{x} = f_{y} = 0$, $f_{x} = 3x³ - 4y$ and $f_{y} = 3y³ - 4x$. Therefore $f_{xx} = 9x²$, $f_{yy} = 9y²$, and $f_{xy} = f_{yx} = -4$.

Hessian matrix determinant is positive for P($\frac{2}{\sqrt3},\frac{2}{\sqrt3},-14)$ and Q($\frac{-2}{\sqrt3}$,$\frac{-2}{\sqrt3}$,-14), so they are minimum points.

And R(0,0,2) is a saddle point.

Is this correct?

Comment: there is no z here. how 3rd coordinate in P and Q.

Comment: should be $f_x=4x^3-4y$ (and similar for $f_y$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM $$x^4+y^4+2\geq4\sqrt[4]{x^4y^4}=4|xy|\geq4xy.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=1$, which gives that $0$ is a minimal value.